# XML DigestValue Re-calculate

Tags: php, xml, soap, digital-signature, wsse

I got correctly signed XML file generated by SoapUI. Code below is part of WSSE Header.

```
<ds:Reference URI="#id-AF3B7DA5121961AAD81538052175642352">
       <ds:Transforms>
         <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
         <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="k20 k201 v20 v201 v202 w" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
       </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>1rHcIC43O2CYNQesaNK/uQpnJ8M=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

As we can see the DigestValue is equal to **1rHcIC43O2CYNQesaNK/uQpnJ8M=** but after my calculation is equal to **sc6nLxoiPHloI1X/ufbMEMFEd6c=**

My canonicalized Body element (c14n) looks as follows:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-AF3B7DA5121961AAD81538052175642352"><v20:WyszukanieReceptWystawiajacegoRequest><kryteriaWyszukiwaniaRecept></kryteriaWyszukiwaniaRecept></v20:WyszukanieReceptWystawiajacegoRequest></soapenv:Body>
```

I am writing in PHP. To calculate DigestValue I'm using:

```
$canonicalizedXml = $doc->C14N(true, false, null, ['k20', 'k201', 'v20', 'v201', 'v202', 'w']);
$hash = sha1($canonicalizedXml, true);
$digestValue = base64_encode($hash);
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved - To use C14N we need to load whole document and after that load the body element. C14N will add some attributes to body from root tag.

```
$bodyNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Body')->item(0);
$canonicalizedXml = $bodyNode->C14N(true, false, null, ['k20', 'k201', 'v20', 'v201', 'v202', 'w']);
$hash = sha1($canonicalizedXml, true);
$digestValue = base64_encode($hash);
```